# Why does R not break inside a while loop?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I have this function:

```
err_min <- function(){
  eta <- 0.1
  e <- err(uv)
  i <- 1
  cat(e," ", i, "\n")
  while (e > 10^-14){
    delta_e <- grad_err(uv)
    cat(sum(delta_e^2),"\n")
    uv <- uv - eta * delta_e
    e <- err(uv)
    cat(delta_e, " ", e," ", i, "\n")
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
```

When I am debugging it in RStudio I put in a breakpoint inside the body of the while loop but when I source the file the code never stops inside the loop although the loop does run as I get the output. If I put a breakpoint before the start of the while loop and step through then the entire while loop gets selected when I get to it and then the next step skips over the whole loop.

I'm using RStudio version 0.98.507 on Mac. To debug I'm visually placing a breakpoint inside the loop on the left margin and then sourcing my .R file. It looks like the command that is being run is debugSource("pathtomyfile")

I converted my while loop to a repeat loop and the debugger stops inside just fine. Convert it back to while loop and the breakpoint is not respected again.

Comment: Don't you think it is more a [Rstudio problem](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us)?

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: *How* are you debugging?  via `debug` , e.g.?

Comment: Updated above with requested info.

Comment: Debugging has improved a lot in RStudio since 0.98.507. You might want to try upgrading to the newest version of RStudio; I can't reproduce your problem there.